# Highcharts - how to correctly align x-axis ticks when plotOptions.column.crisp set to false

Tags: highcharts

I recently found that there is a built-in option to disable crisp for `bar` and `column` charts, which is awesome! However, I noticed that x-axis ticks slightly off (I believe ticks distance gets calculated based on crisp-true). Is there a way to align them properly?
Here are docs https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.column.crisp

Updated example:

https://jsfiddle.net/bqo9dv5a/

Ideally, I want ticks to be centered for each column.
[image: ticks should be slightly shifted to the right]
Thank you!

Comment: Can you post a print? I can't see the diference changing `crisp` between `true` or `false` on that example you provided.

Comment: Is the behaviour, which you had described, visible in the demo which you shared? Could you point it out? I am not sure what you have in mind.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, I just updated description, please take a look.

Comment: The only solution which came to my mind is to do some changes with the border and point width. Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/yewsm863/, however, this solution makes the chart a little hazy - that's why the crisp logic was implemented.

Answer (score 0):

I found this parameter on documentation (`xAxis.offset`), maybe it will help achieve what you want.

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.offset

Live Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/yaxis/offset/